# Error - DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: WorkItemId duplicates value on record with id:

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

```
    global  class SkillsBasedRoutingToPropertyOwner {
      public static Id propertyOwnerId;
      public class TranscriptInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
      public ID getroutableID;
         @InvocableVariable(required=true)
          public String geteFileNumber;
          }
     public class TranscriptOutput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
      public Boolean isRouted;
    }


          @InvocableMethod
      public static void  routeUsingSkills(List<TranscriptInput> getTranscripts)
         {
    
    
            Case cs = new Case();
    
            LiveChatTranscript transcriptRecord;
         for (TranscriptInput input : getTranscripts) 
                 {
        cs = [Select Id,PropertyCase__r.Name,PropertyCase__r.Property_Record_Owner__c  from Case 
         where CaseNumber =: input.geteFileNumber];
            transcriptRecord = [Select Id from LiveChatTranscript where Id =:input.getroutableID];
          

    }
    propertyOwnerId = cs.PropertyCase__r.Property_Record_Owner__c;
            createPendingServiceRouting(transcriptRecord);
        }
       


    public  static void createPendingServiceRouting(LiveChatTranscript chat) {
    // Create a new SkillsBased PendingServiceRouting
       Id chatId = chat.Id;
        PendingServiceRouting psrObj = new PendingServiceRouting
        (
        CapacityWeight = 1,
        IsReadyForRouting =FALSE,
        RoutingModel  = 'MostAvailable',
        RoutingPriority = 1,
        RoutingType = 'SkillsBased',
        ServiceChannelId = getChannelId(),
        WorkItemId = chatId,
        PushTimeout = 0
        );
    insert psrObj;
    psrObj = [select id, IsReadyForRouting from PendingServiceRouting where id = : psrObj.id];
    
    // Now add SkillRequirement(s) to the PendingServiceRouting
    String propertyOwnerSkill = 'S'+propertyOwnerId;
    SkillRequirement srObj = new SkillRequirement
        (
        RelatedRecordId = psrObj.id,
        SkillId = getSkillId(propertyOwnerSkill),
        SkillLevel = 10
        );
    insert srObj; 
    // Update PendingServiceRouting as IsReadyForRouting
  
    psrObj.IsReadyForRouting = TRUE;
    update psrObj; 
  

}

static String getChannelId() {
    ServiceChannel channel = [Select Id From ServiceChannel Where RelatedEntity = 'LiveChatTranscript'];
    return channel.Id;
}

static String getSkillId(String propertyOwnerSkillName) {
    
    Skill skill = [Select Id From Skill Where DeveloperName = :propertyOwnerSkillName];
    return skill.Id;
    
}
```

}

when one agent declines the request then this class is invoked from Einstein bot to route chat to another skill agent.

but i am getting error when i am passing workitem id in pending service routing
Error -  DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: WorkItemId duplicates value on record with id:

Comment: Must be duplicate PSRs

Comment: How i can handle these problem ?